# Split hunks with Gitkraken

Tags: gitkraken

After making changes to a tracked files in a Git repository, GitKraken allows you to view default hunks per file.  You are given the option to Stage or Discard these hunks.

`git add --patch` provides the option to split hunks into smaller hunks.  I am wondering whether this functionality exists within GitKraken and, if so, how to utilize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Gitkraken's diff view you can stage/unstage/discard multiple lines by selecting them (click and drag over the lines, the text of the lines is now marked blue) and then right click to choose what you want to do.

For staging single lines there is also a green plus which appears next to the line when you hover your mouse over it.
Click on the green plus to stage the line.

[This Gitkraken support site](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-commits/staging/) shows this in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the context menu when selecting multiple lines]

Comment: This is equivalent to the functionality I'm looking for, so I will mark this as the correct answer.